# npm install host key verification failed

Tags: npm, ssh, bitbucket

I ran npm install in angular2+ project directory and got below error which I cannot understand at all.

> ```
> npm ERR! Error while executing:
> npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@bitbucket.org/path/projectname.git
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
> npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> npm ERR! and the repository exists.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
> ```

I have created ssh key on bitbucket and account and saved it on drive. |
I have clone project from bitbucket.
What does this error has to do with that?

As I am new on project so don't have much knowledge.

Do I need to provide ssh key while npm install as well?

Please let me know if I can provide more info related to question.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you solve this issue?
I faced the same issue 
If you give a hint, it would be helpful for me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check the npm version that you are using. Npm comes bundled with node and you shouldn't have multiple instances on your classpath.

> Hey yup, I thought as much, but seeing as I had updated npm to the
>   latest version ( I even uninstalled node and reinstalled ) with the
>   same result. npm -v still showed the same version - 1.4.9.
>
> FYI for others that may have the same issue. I also have Chocolatey
>   installed, and it seems that npm was also installed via Chocolately
>   which seems to overide the npm path. Uninstalling npm from Chocolately
>   resolved the npm version issue.
>
> After that angular/cli installs correctly from npm.
>
> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6313#issuecomment-301360623